# While login using email-Id how to get username related to email and store it in session variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have created log in form using parameter email-id and password and with session variable I have store email-id in session variable but instead of email id I want to get username and stores in session variable associated with that email id stored in database. Below i have provided code. Please help if you know how to do this?

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString);
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Registration where emailId =@emailId and password=@password", con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailId", loginUser.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", loginPass.Text);

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    Session["loginUser"] = loginUser.Text;//stores email id
    Response.Redirect("~/UserHome.aspx");
}
```

Comment: What's the column name that stores the user name?

Comment: i have use fullname that stores the username in database

Answer (score 1):

Since the user name is stored in `fullname` column in the database, you can get it by using `dt.Rows[0]["fullname"].ToString()`

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    Session["loginUser"] = dt.Rows[0]["fullname"].ToString(); //stores user name
    Response.Redirect("~/UserHome.aspx");
}
```